# How to center vertically bootstrap 3 modal loaded remotely

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 modal for the best of my knowledge by default had no built in option to centralize it vertically , i did a search and i found this code on stackoverflow that works fine if the modal is local.

My issue is that the modal when loaded remotely does not show up vertically centralized the first time after loading.

For the next other show and hide times works fine.

What should i take in my consideration to fix it since the first load ?

```
    (function($) {
    "use strict";
    function positionModals(e) {
        var $this = $(this).css('display', 'block'),
            $window = $(window),
            $dialog = $this.find('.modal-dialog'),
            offset = ($window.height() - $window.scrollTop() - $dialog.height()) / 2,
            marginBottom = parseInt($dialog.css('margin-bottom'), 10);

        $dialog.css('margin-top', offset < marginBottom ? marginBottom : offset);
    }

    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', positionModals);

    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
        $('.modal:visible').each(positionModals);
    });
    }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you instance the modal because it doesn't have content yet it just have height of 0px, then on the second step when it receive the content it loads it, but the modal has been already instanced with height 0 and positioned with this height in the centre of the screen.

What you could do is to listen for 'loaded.bs.modal' and trigger window resize like so:

```
$(document).on('loaded.bs.modal', '.modal', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Hope that helps